# $model->get() returns soft deletes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I run the following method, it returns a collection with soft deletes included...and obviously, it shouldn't.

```
return $twitter_oauth->get();
```

I think it might be the boot function in my `TwitterOAuth` model. I use the boot meth below to soft delete relevant models (works as it should).

```
public static function boot()
{
    TwitterOAuth::deleting(function($twitter_oauth) {
        $twitter_oauth->posts()->delete();
    });

    TwitterOAuth::restoring(function($twitter_oauth) {
        $twitter_oauth->posts()->withTrashed()->restore();
    });
}
```

**Now if I** remove the boot method and run the same `get` query, soft deletes do not appear in the collection. Weird. Anyone have an experience or run into this issue - or see my problem?

I know I could use `whereNull` in my queries, but that seems like a hack. There must be a better way...

Comment: $twitter_oauth->all(); also returns a collection with soft deletes included ?

Comment: Yup! It's essentially the same thing...I tested it before.

Comment: Do your model have SoftDeletes trait ?

Comment: Indeed. I can soft delete and restore soft deletes fine. Boot method works as it should. Issue is retrieving 'TwitterOAuth` collection. Includes the soft deletes. If I remove my boot method, soft deletes ARE NOT included with my `get()` call. Weird...

Comment: can you use something like ```TwitterOAuth::deleting(function(TwitterOAuth $twitter_oauth) {
        $twitter_oauth->posts()->delete();
    });```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to include `parent::boot();` in my boot method. Solved it.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    TwitterOAuth::deleting(function($twitter_oauth) {
        $twitter_oauth->posts()->delete();
    });

    TwitterOAuth::restoring(function($twitter_oauth) {
        $twitter_oauth->posts()->withTrashed()->restore();
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah...was beating my head against the wall. Learn something new every day lol